# Is gaussian window open command is ./gview?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

how to install and run gauss view file?

```
 export GV_DIR=/gaussian/gview
 export LIBPATH=/gaussian/gview
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/gaussian/gview/lib
 PATH=$PATH:/gaussian/gview
 alias gv='gview.exe'
 cd gv
./gview
```

After thar gaussian window is expected to be opened. But there is an error showing that bash: ./gview: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't a problem with your script, you'd have the same problem if you tried to run it from the terminal. You need to change `#!/bin/csh` in `./gview` so it refers to the actual location of CSH on your system. It might be named `tcsh`.

Comment: Or maybe it's not in your distribution, so you need to install it.

Comment: Writing scripts in C shell is such a bad idea (see http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) I wouldn't waste time with a program that does this.

Comment: Did you really name a directory with a `.exe` extension? That's typically used for executable programs on Windows.

Comment: Aliases are only substituted for command names, not for arguments.